# php pear character encoding

Tags: php, pear

I have some issue with pear since i am beginner in it.
Two characters(ő and ü) which is correctly stored in the db appearing 
on the php page as ?.

I was able to write out correctly the characters in a normal php page by:

```
mysqli_query($dbc,'SET NAMES UTF8');
```

This solved that problem but i don't know how to use this in pear.

I use this command for sql accesing

```
$dg->bind('SELECT * FROM person', $options, 'MDB2');
```

I try to use this analog:

```
 $dg->bind('SET NAMES UTF8', $options, 'MDB2');
```

but this isn't working gives me MDB2 Error: unknown error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extend class from Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_MDB2  to get
   acces to protected _connect() function
2. Take instantiated databased object like that

   `//fill all needed options to create object
   $dataSource = new Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_MDB2_Extended();
   $mdb2 = $dataSource->connect();
   $mdb2->exec("SET NAMES utf8");`
3. Bind created data source to your Structures_DataGrid  with bindDataSource
4. Run $dg->bind('SELECT * FROM person', $options, 'MDB2');

Something like that. I don't check that code.

Comment: MDB2 is installed but i got :
Fatal error: Class 'Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_MDB2_Extended' not found in 
Also try to install the Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_MDB2_Extended but i got no release found error

Comment: You need extend class Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_MDB2_Extended from class Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_MDB2

Comment: yes i found i was on a wrong way.
So i extend like this:
 class Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_MDB2_Extended extends Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_MDB2
 {
  protected _connect() ;
 }

Comment: not protected _connect();  but   public function connect() { return parent::_connect(); }

Comment: i modified this line: $mdb2 = $dataSource->connect(); to  $mdb2 = $dataSource->connect($dsn); now works great!
thank you for your help!

Comment: sorry i am not able to vote up your answer i have too less credit